# why same size of struct objects

Tags: c++

Below are two structures defined in C/C++:

```
   struct a

    {        
       static int i;
       void fun() {int i;}

    };
    struct b
    {

       static int i;    
    };
    a obj1;
    b obj2;
```

why sizeof of both obj1 and obj2 are same?

Comment: Why wouldn't they be? They are both empty classes. BTW your class definitions are both missing a trailing `;`.

Comment: `void fun() {int i;}` ist just a declaration of a member function. This takes no space at all.

Comment: @MichaelWalz It is also  *definition*, so it could take space, although not in the class.

Comment: @juanchopanza right, but it doesn't take space anyway, unless we have virtual functions, then we have the firtual function table pointer which takes up 4 or 8 bytes depending on the compiler.

Comment: @MichaelWalz Code usually takes space.

Comment: Functions are not stored in the class object.

Answer (score 3):

Non-virtual member functions and static members don't affect the size of an object, as they aren't stored inside the object.

Adding one or more *virtual* member functions would increase the size by an implementation-specific amount, usually the size of a pointer.